# Uncaught ReferenceError: GM_notification is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tampermonkey

I am trying to have a Tampermonkey script send me desktop notification, but this API is not working:

```
(function() {
    'use strict'

    var timer = setInterval( () => {
        var categories = document.querySelectorAll('.am-category ')
        for (const category of categories) {
            var title = category.querySelector('.am-category-title')
            console.log(title.textContent.trim())
            if (title.textContent.includes('match')) {
                var notificationOptions = { title: 'Title', text: 'text', image: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/geLPT.png' }
                GM_notification(notificationOptions)
            }
        }
    }, 5000)
})()
```

The output I am receiving is:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: GM_notification is not defined
    at eval (userscript.html?name=my-userscript.user.js&id=618b836d-33a4-4b27-87bd-9dc8929c4e2a:24)
```

Do I have to do anything to enable this?
The docs seem to imply it was readily usable:
https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#GM_notification

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I did a quick peek at the docs maybe you need to add `// @grant GM_notification`

Comment: @RolandStarke Thanks, I found it myself, and answered, while you were commenting.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I figured it out myself.
Apparently this function needs to be made available to the script by using the [`@grant`](https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#_grant) header:

```
// @grant        GM_notification
```

to the `==UserScript==` block comment.
I coincidentally found this in the *Greasemonkey* documentation.