# Unable to get GM_notification function to work in Tampermonkey userscript (chrome, OSX)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I'm trying to re-write some of my Tampermonkey scripts to use some of the built in TM/GM functions, but I can't get them to work. An example is the GM_Notification function.

I'm testing it out using the [example GM_notification](https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php?locale=en#api:GM_notification) from the documentation. Here is the complete userscript file contents:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name   Test Notification
// @namespace http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version   2024-01-06
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author    You
// @match  https://gist.github.com/EtienneDG/fe32d3213d87f79e0da0f829e73ee4ab
// @icon   https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?sz=64&domain=github.com
// @grant  GM_notification
// @grant  GM.notification
// @grant unsafeWindow
// @sandbox JavaScript
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
  'use strict'

  console.log('Loaded test notification')

  console.log('About to execute GM_notification...');

  GM_notification({
    text: "This is the notification message.",
    title: "Notification Title",
    url: 'https:/google.com/',
    onclick: (event) => {
      // The userscript is still running, so don't open example.com
      event.preventDefault();
      // Display an alert message instead
      alert('I was clicked!')
    },
  });

  console.log('Executed GM_notification')
})()
```

And when I go to the page that loads this script, I get absolutely no notification/alert, or even an error.
The console output is below:

```
content: normal start event processing for lr2kbof7.baa (1 to run)
VM3242 content.js:55 env: schedule "Test Notification" for document-idle
VM3242 content.js:53 env: inject "Test Notification" now
VM3242 content.js:73 content: DOMContentLoaded
VM3242 content.js:54 env: run "Test Notification" now  (0 requires)
userscript.html?name=Test-Notification.user.js&id=a8f4d506-9af0-45b8-8eed-362488ac963e:21 Loaded test notification
userscript.html?name=Test-Notification.user.js&id=a8f4d506-9af0-45b8-8eed-362488ac963e:23 About to execute GM_notification...
userscript.html?name=Test-Notification.user.js&id=a8f4d506-9af0-45b8-8eed-362488ac963e:37 Executed GM_notification
VM3242 content.js:73 content: load
```

So the script clearly runs, but I don't see any notification or any error in the console logs.

I have tried using the `async GM.notification` as well:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name   Test Notification
// @namespace http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version   2024-01-06
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author    You
// @match  https://gist.github.com/EtienneDG/fe32d3213d87f79e0da0f829e73ee4ab
// @icon   https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?sz=64&domain=github.com
// @grant  GM_notification
// @grant  GM.notification
// @grant unsafeWindow
// @sandbox JavaScript
// ==/UserScript==

(async function() {
  'use strict'

  console.log('Loaded test notification')

  console.log('About to execute await GM.notification...');

  const clicked = await GM.notification({ text: "Click me." });
  console.log('clicked:',clicked)

  console.log('Executed await GM.notification')
})()
```

But it was the same thing (no notification or errors)

**I have tried a few things while debugging:**

1. Trying with the other `@sandbox` values: MAIN_WORLD, ISOLATED_WORLD, USERSCRIPT_WORLD, raw, DOM
2. Does't seem to be any permissions issues with the TM plugin or script
3. The **Add GM functions to this or window** is set to **On** in the script settings
4. Set **Run At** to: **document-start, document-body, document-end**
5. For the **Position** setting, I tried **1**, **3** and **7**
6. Consulted the Google Gods, and found some similar threads (Example: [Uncaught ReferenceError: GM_notification is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67804554/uncaught-referenceerror-gm-notification-is-not-defined)), but ultimately I haven't found anything that fixes it.

**Local Specs:**

- OS: macOS Big Sur
- Browser: Chrome Version 120.0.6099.129 (Official Build) (x86_64)
- Tampermonkey Version: v5.0.0

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Must be something on your end, I get notification just fine with your original script.
https://i.imgur.com/T156CCD.png (although tested on Windows 10 w/Edge)

Comment: Works for me as well. Check extension permissions and see [the extension's console](https://www.tampermonkey.net/faq.php#Q600).

Comment: @vanowm Yes, I agree with you. I just wasn't able to figure out what it was... But I found the answer, It wasn't the extension settings or settings in chrome, but system permission settings for chrome - I had notifications disabled (not sure when I did that).

Comment: @double-beep It was actually my _System Preferences/Permissions_ within my Macbook. I posted an answer, and ill accept it tomorrow. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer (thanks to [this](https://www.makeuseof.com/google-chrome-notifications-not-working-fixes/)).

It wasn't the extension settings or security settings within Chrome, but the system security systems *for* Chrome. I went to my *System Preferences* > *Notifications* > Looked for *Chrome* and noticed it was disabled:

[image: System Notification Preferences for Chrome]

Once enabled, the notifications worked just fine.

Thanks!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).